# Passing an argument to a variable

Tags: python

I am having a simple problem of passing an inputted command line argument string into a variable for use later in my program. Any help is greatly appreciated! Here is what I have so far:

```
import argparse

thing1 = ''
thing2 = ''
thing3 = ''`

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Generic Argument Framework')
parser.add_argument('-v1', '--variable1', help='input for variable 1',required=True,)
parser.add_argument('-v2', '--variable2', help='input for variable 2',required=True,)
parser.add_argument('-v3', '--variable3', help='input for variable 3',required=True,)

args = parser.parse_args()

print 'variable1: ' + args.variable1
print 'variable2: ' + args.variable2
print 'variable3: ' + args.variable3

args.variable1 = thing1
args.variable2 = thing2
args.variable3 = thing3



print thing1
print thing2
print thing3






—————————————————————————————
Output from terminal is:

python argument.py -v1 skittles -v2 kitkat -v3 snickers
variable1: skittles
variable2: kitkat
variable3: snickers



—————————————————————————————
```

So I have the entered values from the option being passed to the “ arg.variable” but 
how do I get that out of the args.variable1, 2, 3 INTO the variable thing1, 2, 3?? The print statements work for args.variables, but when i print what is within thing1,2,3 it is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't assigned the value of the `thing` variables to any arguments.

Instead of

```
args.variable1 = thing1
args.variable2 = thing2
args.variable3 = thing3
```

Use

```
thing1 = args.variable1
thing2 = args.variable2
thing3 = args.variable3
```

And have a look at some basic programming tutorials, this is called assignment.